# ByDefault NSURLConnection is synchronous or asynchronous

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

> ByDefault NSURLConnection is synchronous or asynchronous

What should be the answer for the same. And one more question is:

> What is the difference between delegate and notification.

I know the difference, but I'm confused, the notification is local or Apple notification. Or there is some other feature in iPhone. Becuase i have read about `NSNotificationCenter` also.

Comment: This forum is not to discuss interview questions, its for developers. Hope you understand!

Comment: For question (1) read the docs.  For question (2), you should ask for clarification from the interviewer since there are two potential meanings of "notification" here.  (Although you could probably deduce it from context...)

Comment: @NSBum , i have read whole NSURLConnection page in apple developer site, but i didn't get. They are saying NSURLConnection could be both, but default behavior is not specified. Maybe i missed out something.@Prateek, i have seen few post, in which they are asking interview questions for iphone, so i thought we can ask this type of questions too. I apologise, if we can not ask this type of questions.

Comment: I think i should delete this post, i am getting so much of negative marking. I am sorry if the question is not so much useful.

Comment: @knowledgeseeker do it immediately or may be you get more downvotes too.

Comment: @knowledgeseeker If you read a documentation for one single class and you didn't get it, then you obviously wasn't fit for the job.

Comment: i am not able to delete it, it's saying you have answer, you can not delete it.

Comment: i think i asked world's worst question. Please someone close this post.

Comment: don't worry request the community to vote up your this post, but before that edit it.

Comment: Please do some up voting for this question, i edited it. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Q:**
    ByDefault NSURLConnection is synchronous or asynchronous

**A:**
    It depend which method you calling in NSURLConnection. But most of the method are related asynchronous. Except one that is sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:

Loading Data Synchronously

```
+ sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:
```

Loading Data Asynchronously

```
+ connectionWithRequest:delegate:
– initWithRequest:delegate:
– initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately:
+ sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:
– start
```

**Q:**
    What is the difference between delegate and notification.

**A:**
    Use delegate for one to one object communication. e.g Event received from objA call it's delegate objB to execute it.
Use notification for one to many object communication. e.g. ObjA, ObjB registered as observer on ObjA Event. When event occur, it will send the message to both ObjA and ObjB.

Comment: thanks for such a nice and clear reply.